# Django too slow and trying to load images

Tags: django, performance, static

I don't know why, but django is too slow to refresh the page (at my local dev server). I was looking at the log and it shows many times:

```
[31/Jan/2014 08:14:28] "GET /questoes/fisica/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA
AANSUhEUgAAACIAAAAiCAYAAAA6RwvCAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllP
AAAA7dJREFUeNqsWM1PE0EU3+7ShdJKoTRA8UYgIUKM3rmaEI0euXsw0YMHIZEbxBijEiIHLkb/A44SD
YlXzkYPGBM+ri1NWz7aUmhp6+9tps10mLfdfrzkl2535r39zc77mvUdHh4abUoUCAD3xP/fQAFItWJkY
mLC+e1p8eGPgQcC08ycf8BPgW2vhr0SeQa8AWIe5k4LvATiwCrwtZmS2WT8IfAL+OKRhCoxoftH2GqLy
BLwHbhvdC53ha2lVrfmE/DKzbLP5yubplnt7e310f+rq6tqpVLxVatVy0VtHbgNLHohsupGIhQKFQG7v
79f+8CLiwsjl8sVAZsxQbYTwFrDwpTwpaj4ptPu6+vLDw4OBkHA014QobOzs3yhUAgyUx4BP2rhq/rIe
53GwMBAeXx83DMJEpobi8WCpMtMWeOc9TkwoyMRjUattrMedBkyM+KZN4isqDMDgUCuExIyGbKlGVpRi
Szo8kQ4HA4ZXRLGVuzo6GhBJjKviw6dT5TLZSOTyRinp6cGQrV+n67hnEY6nTaur6+1PkM2NWTm5fCd0
xDRhh89CKHpXCMijLGxMef6+PjYiRSSUqlUv6/arOlKMlcjQlV0qsGDTZPehpYIxurXRCSRSFByq5NQ5
6hvhWwj8cm2p7A9UdKYVBX8fn+F2+tIJGIgmzaQkUnYtm0MDw+zvsLYniQiEc2q/WxxwmqRHxrISA9xx
iyLDzTGdsRsJwJoK3QPo3vctnhpAzLqTexhiVOg6JAdU5bLy0vHZ+Ro8mg7Q0QO1LvwenZZJycnN3yCI
PsMRRYnjO0DU/SY+wprW7fiWmjKJMgnUIcafEaeoxZCJWJI9lH4UjV2u6pSPp/XJR9jaGiIKrERDAbrj
llzYOQJZ4zm6ISxuSsntB3gqTyazWZtMowa0aBFb4HegC6aRkZG2C2hLSObmqEdOcVvUdJUZyBlZ7tVa
1ASdEUvjW3ZUqvvO82e3kqlUuVOSZANvBFd0fugawM2VKclOT8/tzohQ7pkgzn/rHNdvLbLJkPxeDzHR
RIXIaTDkCB57XacoJPZW8bZQpSskslk0Y0QjdEcmstsB8myegrsYbqmENfJU3dOpZyOEwjdCqLIWUyxW
KygVzHFccJ2eVkbar/qdq5ZFC3/R5dUb6EBsqQmyEtLuawj0eykRwpPgL0uRO+esLXW7tmX9nEWeAEk2
yCQFLqzzb4MeK3Zn4FRsapNEXqGy2eJTTF3VOh27bOE/Ia2pQ81YeCO+P+XknGrH2pq8l+AAQDv/n2Gm
q99BgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== HTTP/1.1" 404 16622
[31/Jan/2014 08:14:28] "GET /questoes/fisica/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA
AANSUhEUgAAACIAAAAiCAYAAAA6RwvCAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllP
AAAA7dJREFUeNqsWM1PE0EU3+7ShdJKoTRA8UYgIUKM3rmaEI0euXsw0YMHIZEbxBijEiIHLkb/A44SD
YlXzkYPGBM+ri1NWz7aUmhp6+9tps10mLfdfrzkl2535r39zc77mvUdHh4abUoUCAD3xP/fQAFItWJkY
mLC+e1p8eGPgQcC08ycf8BPgW2vhr0SeQa8AWIe5k4LvATiwCrwtZmS2WT8IfAL+OKRhCoxoftH2GqLy
BLwHbhvdC53ha2lVrfmE/DKzbLP5yubplnt7e310f+rq6tqpVLxVatVy0VtHbgNLHohsupGIhQKFQG7v
79f+8CLiwsjl8sVAZsxQbYTwFrDwpTwpaj4ptPu6+vLDw4OBkHA014QobOzs3yhUAgyUx4BP2rhq/rIe
53GwMBAeXx83DMJEpobi8WCpMtMWeOc9TkwoyMRjUattrMedBkyM+KZN4isqDMDgUCuExIyGbKlGVpRi
Szo8kQ4HA4ZXRLGVuzo6GhBJjKviw6dT5TLZSOTyRinp6cGQrV+n67hnEY6nTaur6+1PkM2NWTm5fCd0
xDRhh89CKHpXCMijLGxMef6+PjYiRSSUqlUv6/arOlKMlcjQlV0qsGDTZPehpYIxurXRCSRSFByq5NQ5
6hvhWwj8cm2p7A9UdKYVBX8fn+F2+tIJGIgmzaQkUnYtm0MDw+zvsLYniQiEc2q/WxxwmqRHxrISA9xx
iyLDzTGdsRsJwJoK3QPo3vctnhpAzLqTexhiVOg6JAdU5bLy0vHZ+Ro8mg7Q0QO1LvwenZZJycnN3yCI
PsMRRYnjO0DU/SY+wprW7fiWmjKJMgnUIcafEaeoxZCJWJI9lH4UjV2u6pSPp/XJR9jaGiIKrERDAbrj
llzYOQJZ4zm6ISxuSsntB3gqTyazWZtMowa0aBFb4HegC6aRkZG2C2hLSObmqEdOcVvUdJUZyBlZ7tVa
1ASdEUvjW3ZUqvvO82e3kqlUuVOSZANvBFd0fugawM2VKclOT8/tzohQ7pkgzn/rHNdvLbLJkPxeDzHR
RIXIaTDkCB57XacoJPZW8bZQpSskslk0Y0QjdEcmstsB8myegrsYbqmENfJU3dOpZyOEwjdCqLIWUyxW
KygVzHFccJ2eVkbar/qdq5ZFC3/R5dUb6EBsqQmyEtLuawj0eykRwpPgL0uRO+esLXW7tmX9nEWeAEk2
yCQFLqzzb4MeK3Zn4FRsapNEXqGy2eJTTF3VOh27bOE/Ia2pQ81YeCO+P+XknGrH2pq8l+AAQDv/n2Gm
q99BgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== HTTP/1.1" 404 16622
[31/Jan/2014 08:14:36] "GET /questoes/fisica/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA
AANSUhEUgAAACIAAAAiCAYAAAA6RwvCAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllP
AAAA7dJREFUeNqsWM1PE0EU3+7ShdJKoTRA8UYgIUKM3rmaEI0euXsw0YMHIZEbxBijEiIHLkb/A44SD
YlXzkYPGBM+ri1NWz7aUmhp6+9tps10mLfdfrzkl2535r39zc77mvUdHh4abUoUCAD3xP/fQAFItWJkY
mLC+e1p8eGPgQcC08ycf8BPgW2vhr0SeQa8AWIe5k4LvATiwCrwtZmS2WT8IfAL+OKRhCoxoftH2GqLy
BLwHbhvdC53ha2lVrfmE/DKzbLP5yubplnt7e310f+rq6tqpVLxVatVy0VtHbgNLHohsupGIhQKFQG7v
79f+8CLiwsjl8sVAZsxQbYTwFrDwpTwpaj4ptPu6+vLDw4OBkHA014QobOzs3yhUAgyUx4BP2rhq/rIe
53GwMBAeXx83DMJEpobi8WCpMtMWeOc9TkwoyMRjUattrMedBkyM+KZN4isqDMDgUCuExIyGbKlGVpRi
Szo8kQ4HA4ZXRLGVuzo6GhBJjKviw6dT5TLZSOTyRinp6cGQrV+n67hnEY6nTaur6+1PkM2NWTm5fCd0
xDRhh89CKHpXCMijLGxMef6+PjYiRSSUqlUv6/arOlKMlcjQlV0qsGDTZPehpYIxurXRCSRSFByq5NQ5
6hvhWwj8cm2p7A9UdKYVBX8fn+F2+tIJGIgmzaQkUnYtm0MDw+zvsLYniQiEc2q/WxxwmqRHxrISA9xx
iyLDzTGdsRsJwJoK3QPo3vctnhpAzLqTexhiVOg6JAdU5bLy0vHZ+Ro8mg7Q0QO1LvwenZZJycnN3yCI
PsMRRYnjO0DU/SY+wprW7fiWmjKJMgnUIcafEaeoxZCJWJI9lH4UjV2u6pSPp/XJR9jaGiIKrERDAbrj
llzYOQJZ4zm6ISxuSsntB3gqTyazWZtMowa0aBFb4HegC6aRkZG2C2hLSObmqEdOcVvUdJUZyBlZ7tVa
1ASdEUvjW3ZUqvvO82e3kqlUuVOSZANvBFd0fugawM2VKclOT8/tzohQ7pkgzn/rHNdvLbLJkPxeDzHR
RIXIaTDkCB57XacoJPZW8bZQpSskslk0Y0QjdEcmstsB8myegrsYbqmENfJU3dOpZyOEwjdCqLIWUyxW
KygVzHFccJ2eVkbar/qdq5ZFC3/R5dUb6EBsqQmyEtLuawj0eykRwpPgL0uRO+esLXW7tmX9nEWeAEk2
yCQFLqzzb4MeK3Zn4FRsapNEXqGy2eJTTF3VOh27bOE/Ia2pQ81YeCO+P+XknGrH2pq8l+AAQDv/n2Gm
q99BgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== HTTP/1.1" 404 16622
[31/Jan/2014 08:14:52] "GET /questoes/fisica/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA
AANSUhEUgAAACIAAAAiCAYAAAA6RwvCAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllP
AAAA7dJREFUeNqsWM1PE0EU3+7ShdJKoTRA8UYgIUKM3rmaEI0euXsw0YMHIZEbxBijEiIHLkb/A44SD
YlXzkYPGBM+ri1NWz7aUmhp6+9tps10mLfdfrzkl2535r39zc77mvUdHh4abUoUCAD3xP/fQAFItWJkY
mLC+e1p8eGPgQcC08ycf8BPgW2vhr0SeQa8AWIe5k4LvATiwCrwtZmS2WT8IfAL+OKRhCoxoftH2GqLy
BLwHbhvdC53ha2lVrfmE/DKzbLP5yubplnt7e310f+rq6tqpVLxVatVy0VtHbgNLHohsupGIhQKFQG7v
79f+8CLiwsjl8sVAZsxQbYTwFrDwpTwpaj4ptPu6+vLDw4OBkHA014QobOzs3yhUAgyUx4BP2rhq/rIe
53GwMBAeXx83DMJEpobi8WCpMtMWeOc9TkwoyMRjUattrMedBkyM+KZN4isqDMDgUCuExIyGbKlGVpRi
Szo8kQ4HA4ZXRLGVuzo6GhBJjKviw6dT5TLZSOTyRinp6cGQrV+n67hnEY6nTaur6+1PkM2NWTm5fCd0
xDRhh89CKHpXCMijLGxMef6+PjYiRSSUqlUv6/arOlKMlcjQlV0qsGDTZPehpYIxurXRCSRSFByq5NQ5
6hvhWwj8cm2p7A9UdKYVBX8fn+F2+tIJGIgmzaQkUnYtm0MDw+zvsLYniQiEc2q/WxxwmqRHxrISA9xx
iyLDzTGdsRsJwJoK3QPo3vctnhpAzLqTexhiVOg6JAdU5bLy0vHZ+Ro8mg7Q0QO1LvwenZZJycnN3yCI
PsMRRYnjO0DU/SY+wprW7fiWmjKJMgnUIcafEaeoxZCJWJI9lH4UjV2u6pSPp/XJR9jaGiIKrERDAbrj
llzYOQJZ4zm6ISxuSsntB3gqTyazWZtMowa0aBFb4HegC6aRkZG2C2hLSObmqEdOcVvUdJUZyBlZ7tVa
1ASdEUvjW3ZUqvvO82e3kqlUuVOSZANvBFd0fugawM2VKclOT8/tzohQ7pkgzn/rHNdvLbLJkPxeDzHR
RIXIaTDkCB57XacoJPZW8bZQpSskslk0Y0QjdEcmstsB8myegrsYbqmENfJU3dOpZyOEwjdCqLIWUyxW
KygVzHFccJ2eVkbar/qdq5ZFC3/R5dUb6EBsqQmyEtLuawj0eykRwpPgL0uRO+esLXW7tmX9nEWeAEk2
yCQFLqzzb4MeK3Zn4FRsapNEXqGy2eJTTF3VOh27bOE/Ia2pQ81YeCO+P+XknGrH2pq8l+AAQDv/n2Gm
q99BgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== HTTP/1.1" 404 16622
```

Look to the timestamp! It's almost 30 seconds during a simple reload...

Does anyone knows how can I solve this? 
I think its anything with staticserve/media files... I think these files are uploaded... (I'm refreshing an article page that was written with html content (so those articles have images etc)

Thank you so much!

**UPDATING:**

My html view:
    {{ question.statement|safe }}

I've the code above in a loop. Statement is a Text field with html content like:

```
<p>Um laborat&oacute;rio realiza exames em que &eacute; poss&iacute;vel<br />observar a taxa de glicose de uma pessoa. Os resultados<br />s&atilde;o analisados de acordo com o quadro a seguir.</p> <p><img src="/media/uploads/questoes/individuais/9000000021%202014-01-31%2015.25.jpg" alt="" width="562" height="272" /></p> <p>Um paciente fez um exame de glicose nesse laborat&oacute;rio e<br />comprovou que estava com hiperglicemia. Sua taxa de glicose<br />era de 300 mg/dL. Seu m&eacute;dico prescreveu um tratamento em<br />duas etapas. Na primeira etapa ele conseguiu reduzir sua<br />taxa em 30% e na segunda etapa em 10%.</p> <p>Ao calcular sua taxa de glicose ap&oacute;s as duas redu&ccedil;&otilde;es, o<br />paciente verificou que estava na categoria de</p>
```

So the content refers to "/media" images that I've uploaded to the server.

And in my html layout I've some images with static tag, like (mostly layout purposes):

```
{% static 'img/ico/icotop.png' %}
```

Is that the problem?

Comment: Can you please post the html and code you wrote in the view.

Comment: zzz. dude are you posting the image into the url? How are you doing this?! But that's what it looks like.  It takes so long because first you upload the entire image in the request url. This is rarely what you want to do. Naturally it gets a 404 response. <insert something derogatory here>

Comment: I've just updated and posted my code as requested!

Answer (score 1):

I think in view.py you are passing the image as Httpesponse without the mimetype. Also Try to avoid django to serve images. Apache/web server can handle that work for you very fast..

Comment: how can I handle it at development stage? I mean, at my localhost tests?

Comment: Can you paste those piece code here? Without looking at code its difficult to guess actually what you wanted to do and what should be done to your problem. Paste it along with file names.